# Attribute ID Selector Determines Field Values in Custom Field Acumatica

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica, erp

I have created a line level field in AP303000 form and I need to have Attribute ID selector

```
namespace MidayaCustomizations
{
    public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
    {
        #region UsrAttributeSelection
        [PXDBString(250)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Attribute ID")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttribute.attributeID>),
            typeof(CSAttribute.attributeID),
            typeof(CSAttribute.description),
            typeof(CSAttribute.controlType))] 
        public virtual string UsrAttributeSelection { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAttributeSelection : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAttributeSelection> { }
        #endregion

        #region UsrAttributeValues
        [PXDBString(250)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Attribute Values")]

        public virtual string UsrAttributeValues { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrAttributeValues : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrAttributeValues> { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And I need to get the Attribute ID from that field and in the UsrAttributeValues field, the values from that particular attribute should be populated (eg- Attribute ID “CSS” is a dropdown field and in UsrAttributeValues field these list of values should be available to be selected).

```
namespace MidayaCustomizations
{
    public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        protected void APTran_UsrAttributeSelection_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            APTran row = (APTran)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            var rowExt = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExt>(row);
           
            List<string> allowedValues = new List<string>();
            List<string> allowedLabels = new List<string>();

            
                foreach (CSAttributeDetail objCSAttributeDetail in PXSelect<CSAttributeDetail,
                                                          Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<Required<APTranExt.usrAttributeSelection>>>>.Select(Base, rowExt.UsrAttributeSelection))


                {
                    allowedValues.Add(objCSAttributeDetail.ValueID);
                    allowedLabels.Add(objCSAttributeDetail.Description);
                }
               
                e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, 10, true, typeof(APTranExt.usrAttributeValues).Name, false, -1, string.Empty, allowedValues.ToArray(), allowedLabels.ToArray(), false, null);
            
        }
            #endregion
        }
}
```

Currently trying to use a field selecting event handler to get the values from Attributes, but I am facing errors, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UsrAttributeSelection is a selector, not a 'dropdown' list. AllowedValues and Allowed labels are for list not selector.  Either it's not a list and you can remove allowed values/labels. Or you have to remove PXSelector and replace it with PXStringList or PXIntList attribute to make it a list.

Comment: I guess you can just move your where condition into the PXSelector attribute instead of having this event handler.

Comment: Can I assume that what you need is to filter the AttributeID selector to only show Attributes that are ComboBoxes? If so I can help you with some sample code to do what you need

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a sample project for you to test. If it works for you I will provide the VS project as well.

In short I am not 100% sure why your code was throwing errors. My technique is very similar. The only difference is that I limited Attributes to Combo and MultiSelect Combo control types only. Also in the Screen you have to turn on Matrix Mode on the Grid and Column in question.

https://drive.govelocit.com/d/f/634034105803123785